# Why does shuffling two different decks yield the same result?

Tags: c#, random, shuffle

First off I have my "Deck" class here. I've just put in the some basic methods, for testing purposes. It's my first go at creating a "card" program.

```
    public class Deck
{
    private int deckCounter = 0;
    private List<Card> deckSize = new List<Card>();
    private List<Card> shuffledDeck = new List<Card>();
    private Random random = new Random();

    public Deck()
    {
    }

    public void Build()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k < 14; k++)
            {
                deckSize.Add(new Card(k.ToString(), i));
            }
        }
    }

    public void Add(Card card)
    {
        deckSize.Add(card);
        deckCounter++;
    }

    public Card RemoveCard()
    {
            Card cardToRemove = deckSize.First();
            deckSize.RemoveAt(0);
            return cardToRemove;
    }

    public void ShowContainedCards()
    {
        int cardCount = 0;
        foreach (Card c in deckSize)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c.ReturnCardInfo());
            cardCount++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(cardCount);
    }

    public void Shuffle()
    {
        while (deckSize.Count != 0)
        {
            int i = random.Next(deckSize.Count);
            shuffledDeck.Add(deckSize[i]);

            deckSize.RemoveAt(i);
        }
        deckSize = shuffledDeck;
    }

    public bool IsEmpty()
    {
        if (deckSize.Any())
        {
            return false;
        }
        else return true;
    }

    public List<Card> GetCardList()
    {
        return deckSize;
    }
}
```

Basicly, what I do is, this:

```
    Deck deck1 = new Deck();
    Deck deck2 = new Deck();

    deck1.Build();
    deck1.Shuffle();
    deck2.Build();
    deck2.Shuffle();
```

After that, I get the exact same shuffle, for deck1 and deck2. Why is that? Also, I'm a newb at this, if you couldn't tell :)

Comment: It says [in the documentation for Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx): "different Random objects that are created in close succession by a call to the default constructor will have identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical sets of random numbers."

Comment: As a side note, see the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), which is a proper shuffle algorithm.

Comment: Closed because the underlying issue is the same and the existing question explains it well.

Comment: your `Shuffle` routine is also not very safe - I'd make `shuffledDeck` a local variable rather than a field and always initialize it with a new `List<>` inside Shuffle. At the moment, you can't call `Shuffle` twice in a sane manner because after the first call, `deckSize` and `shuffledDeck` refer to the same list.

Answer (score 1):

Use the same `Random` class instance in both deck instances:

```
Random random = new Random();
Deck deck1 = new Deck(random);
Deck deck2 = new Deck(random);
```

So, in the constructor:

```
public class Deck
{
    private int deckCounter = 0;
    private List<Card> deckSize = new List<Card>();
    private List<Card> shuffledDeck = new List<Card>();
    private Random random;

    public Deck(Random random)
    {
        this.random = random;
    }
```

The current problem with your code, is that the two instances of `Random` that are created are seeded the same.  This causes them to produce the same results.  Using the same instance of `Random` means the second shuffle will build *on top of* the seeded results of the first shuffle.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite resolution. As a result, different Random objects that are created in close succession by a call to the default constructor will have identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical sets of random numbers.

The same docs also suggest a solution:

> This problem can be avoided by using a single Random object to generate all random numbers.

Hence, one possible solution would be to make your random generator static, so all of your `Deck` instances share the same `Random` instance:

```
private static Random random = new Random();
```

That way, you would even avoid changing any part of the public interface of your `Deck` class.

Answer (score 0):

Computers are inherently *not* random, so any random number generator will actually be using an algorithm to produce output that *looks* random. The thing with this is that there's always a starting point, and if you know where it' starting from, you can predict the outcome. Random number generators therefore have a "seed" which tells it where to start. The same seed will always give the same sequence of "random" numbers.

Both times, you're using `new Random()`, which uses the default seed. In some languages, you'd be advised to pass the current time as a seed, but C# does that for you. However, if you create two `Random` objects close together, they're likely to get the same time, which is what's happening here.

If you made your `Random` static, then all your random numbers would come from the same source, so the two decks would get successive random numbers, not the same ones in parallel.